# Insertion sort in python with negative numbers at the end of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I used the sorting algorithm to sort numbers like positives first and then negatives (swapping in place, you can use variables but **without using any container** variables. Just assume we don't have more memory space for extra containers). So the sorted positive numbers first, then the sorted negatives.

I did it, but I needed another `for` loop for the negatives to sort and insert them at the end of the list.

My question: is there a way to modify the first loop to achieve the same result?
(ie: use only 1 `for` loop)

for example:

```
x = [9, -3, 2, -7, -4, -1, 5, 4]
```

The output should be:

```
[2, 4, 5, 9, -7, -4, -3, -1]
```

Here is my solution (but I used 2 `for` loops, and I want to only use 1):

```
def insertion_sort(data):
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        e = i
        while e > 0 and data[e - 1] > data[e]:
            data[e - 1], data[e] = data[e], data[e - 1]
            e -= 1
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        e = i
        while e > 0 and data[e - 1] < 0:
            if data[e] < 0:
                if data[e - 1] < data[e]:
                    data[e - 1], data[e] = data[e], data[e - 1]
            data[e - 1], data[e] = data[e], data[e - 1]
            e -= 1
    print(data)
```

Comment: Have you considered doing a normal insertion sort, then finding the index at which your list changes from negative to positive, and just re-slicing the list? The algorithm would still be bounded by the sort.

Comment: Yes the idea is good, but re-slicing the list means using extra lists (I said in my question to not use any extra container, just swap elements in place)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to find the pivot value when the numbers start to be positives

```
def insertion_sort(data):

    pivot = -1
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        e = i
        while e > 0 and data[e - 1] > data[e]:
            data[e - 1], data[e] = data[e], data[e - 1]
            if data[e] >= 0 and data[e-1] < 0:
                pivot = e
            e -= 1

    data[-pivot:], data[:-pivot] = data[:pivot], data[pivot:]
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks @Hemerson Tacon but you didn't meet my requirements. I said to to use any extra container variable, but you used neg variable that has a list value. I want a solution that just swap elements "in place". But thanks for trying though

Comment: @FouadDev just fixed the code, it had some errors, now I'm not using extra container anymore

Comment: Since negative values index backwards from the end of a list, that last line can be simplified.

Comment: @FouadDev could you define what you are calling containers? Because the last line of my solution swap values in place  like what is done inside `for`

Comment: Yes @Hemerson Tacon it's actually a good solution. Great job man

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function `is_greater` as follows:

```
def is_greater(x, y):
    if (x < 0 and y < 0) or (x >= 0 and y >= 0):
        return x > y
    return x < 0
```

Then you can use this instead of normal int comparison in your first loop:

```
def insertion_sort(data):
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        e = i
        while e > 0 and is_greater(data[e - 1], data[e]):
            data[e - 1], data[e] = data[e], data[e - 1]
            e -= 1
    print(data)

insertion_sort(d)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 4, 5, 9, -7, -4, -3, -1]
```

Comment: Yup, thanks @slider, that's a good way to go about it. You didn't use any extra container (iterable). You only swapped them in place. good solution

Comment: But I wish I could find a solution without extra function. Just like modifying that only for loop to do the job